# Static IPs through router

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, ip

Don't know of it's even possible, or if it's the right place but here it goes.

Facts:

- I have a router (on lease, can get something else if need be), TL-WR740N.
- My ISP gives me 3 external/global IPs through 3 specific MAC I can set up in the online configuration page that the ISP provides.
- Before using the router I used the main cable going to my PC to connect, for my host I've used one IP, for a virtual guest in VMWare I was using a different IP, one of the 3 available to me, through adapter binding and specific MAC address.

Now that I had to install WiFi for a device in my home, I'm trying out this router my ISP gave me.

The issue I'm having is that now all devices are grouped to just one external IP address, my PC has a local IP in the form of 192.168.0.100, the wireless device has .101. All go out through the IP that is bound to the MAC of my PC, cloned in the conf. page of the router.

I was hoping to use the 3rd MAC and assign that 3rd IP, my ISP offers, to the wireless device and to keep the external IPs I used to assign to my PC and the virtual guest.

So now I need help with this issue... either on this device if possible or if need be what should I get to set it up the way I've explained?

Edit: Would I be able to achieve this if I put a basic switch in front of the Wireless Access Point router? So, WAN connects to the switch and from it a line goes to the WAP and a separate line to my PC's NIC, my connection bypassing the WAP completely.

Comment: Normally you get one external IP, your router's DHCP then assigns and routes to private addresses (ie. like 192.168.1.x).   Today's routers usually have "DHCP Reservations" to make sure a devices always acquires the same private IP, do that you can use your routers port forwarding service, to get specific ports to specific machines from the outside.

Comment: Does the PC/VMWare need to talk to anything on the wireless or does everything just need strict internet only with no file/printer sharing?

Comment: Strict internet and no other in-between links. The thing is I use one IP for "personal space", the VM for work and there that IP has some exposure but is also recognised by the work server and the wifi device just needs internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router model has a single external network card and uses NAT, which is the case with most general purpose home routers. Due to this router will be able to bind with only single external IP address. The devices that connect to your router will be assigned local IP addresses with different range(mostly 192.168.*.*) through NAT. So all your device will ultimately connect with single public IP address that your ISP provided.

Simply use a switch between your devices and ISP to achieve desired configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If your ISP has provided you three IP addresses that are tied to certain MAC addresses and you want to use all three devices concurrently without worrying about how your three devices communicate between themselves, then indeed all you need to do is to put a dumb switch between your three devices and your ISP.

In such case, your three devices will communicate to your ISP over the ARP protocol as if they were directly connected to your ISP's cable. Therefore, this will solve the connectivity issue for all your three devices.

However, if your ISP has not guaranteed that your three devices will pick up IP addresses on the same IP subnet, your devices may or may not be able to communicate between themselves. The discussion of when such communications are possible is well outside of the scope of this topic.